# Please Suggest 3-D Editors to Simulate Suspention of a Bike

Tags: 3d, blender, solidworks, 3d-modelling

I'm going to design a custom frame for a full-suspension bike, and I want to analyse how the suspension works in other bikes.

As far as I can see, I will need to use some software where I can create a frame, moving parts and suspension connections and simulate its movement:

[Bike Suspension Work Example Gif](https://ninerschweiz.ch/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/jet-30trx16tcogmp4-1544200209329.gif)

Please suggest a 3-D editor for Windows, where I can create 3-D model frames, joints and moving mechanical parts, move them and check the result.

I am new to working with 3-D editors, and as far as I understand this is not done in Blender or similar programs for 3-D modelling. (It may be done, but it will probably be too difficult for me). So I ask you to advise me easy to learn programs, if any.

*(Also it would be a huge plus if it is free)*

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use Fusion 360.

https://www.autodesk.com/products/fusion-360/